# Creation of files with control of the names

Tags: linux, bash, loops

I have *n* files, named *f1*, *f2*, ..., *fn*. For each of these files, I have to execute a sed command, and name the new files as *file1*, *file2*, ..., *filen*.

I need the new files to keep the same number as their original ones. Can anyone help?

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
#!/bin/sh 

for element in *
do 
    echo "$element" sed -n '/Col3/p' $element > Quest $element 
done
```

Comment: can you show as what you have tried so far ? (code)

Comment: i'm starting the alogirithm:
#!/bin/sh
# Fichier "liste"

for element in *
   do

    echo "$element"
    sed -n '/Col3/p' $element  > Quest $element

done


It's far from beeing correct, but i'm struggling a little bit

Comment: This is a not a bash script. It's run with `/bin/sh`, so even if it's bash, it's run in POSIX compatibility mode.  Do you want to do this in a Bash-specific way, or are you after a portable solution that will run in other shells too, as your example suggests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/env bash

for FILE in *
do
    [[ "$FILE" =~ [0-9]+$ ]] && mv "$FILE" file${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
done
```

The expression within `[[ ]]` is a test, which tests for a match against a regular expression, which looks for a string ending in a number. If the match is successful, the matched number can be found in the `bash` array variable `BASH_REMATCH` at index `0`. The part after `&&` is executed if the test succeeds, and renames the file to `fileNN`,

Comment: Code-only answers are not terribly useful. Please consider adding some explanatory text.

Answer (score 1):

If we assume that all the your files are in the form in your question...

```
$ ls -l
total 2
-rw-r--r--  1 ghoti  wheel  0 Jan  3 13:20 f1
-rw-r--r--  1 ghoti  wheel  0 Jan  3 13:20 f2
-rw-r--r--  1 ghoti  wheel  0 Jan  3 13:20 f3
-rw-r--r--  1 ghoti  wheel  0 Jan  3 13:20 f4
```

then you're on the right track with a `for` loop. But you probably want to narrow your search to only the files that are important to you.

In bash, you can use `extglob` to control this sort of thing. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s extglob
for file in +([a-z])+([0-9]); do
  echo "Old: $file / New: file${file##[a-z]}"
done
```

This matches any files whose names consist of letters followed by numbers.

If, on the other hand, you want to make this portable, so that it will work in a POSIX shell (since in your question you've specified `/bin/sh`), you might put the detection into the loop itself:

```
#!/bin/sh

for file in *; do
  if ! expr "$file" : '[a-z][a-z]*[0-9][0-9]*$' >/dev/null; then
    continue
  fi
  echo "Old: $file / New: file${file##[a-z]}"
done
```

In both of these examples, we use POSIX "Parameter Expansion" to strip off the letters at the beginning of the filename.